# How to handle compile-dependencies between Hudson jobs?

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, jenkins, hudson, delphi-xe

I have two runtime packages, one referencing the other. In Hudson, I have a build job for each of the two packages (I want test results and coverage reports for each package separately). To compile the second package I need the .dcp file of the first package. What is the best way to provide that file (especially since both project builds can be triggered independently)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first job can use a special (common) folder to deploy the DCP file when the job completed, maybe using a version number in the folder name to keep dependecies clear.
The second job needs to know the folder location, if the file has been deployed once, the second job can be triggered any time without a prior rebuild. Also the completion of the first job can be configured so that it triggers a build of the second job.